# Azure GovCloud Template Error

Tags: json, azure

I am using this template [enter link description here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/301-custom-images-at-scale) and I been working through it to convert it from stock to something I can use in the Azure Government Cloud. I am almost complete but I keep getting this last error that I do not know how to rectify. Maybe someone here with more json experience than I do can find this fix simply.

```html
{
 "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
 "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "parameters": {
  "uniquePrefix": {
   "type": "string",
   "metadata": {
    "description": "This unique prefix will be used on all the objects created as part of this template."
   }
  },
  "transferVMSize": {
   "type": "string",
   "defaultValue": "Standard_D4",
   "allowedValues": [
    "Standard_A4",
    "Standard_A7",
    "Standard_D4",
    "Standard_D14",
    "Standard_D2s_v3"
   ],
   "metadata": {
    "description": "Size of the VM used to transfer the VM image to various storage accounts."
   }
  },
  "computeVMSize": {
   "type": "string",
   "defaultValue": "Standard_A1",
   "allowedValues": [
    "Standard_A1",
    "Standard_A2",
    "Standard_A3",
    "Standard_A4",
    "Standard_A5",
    "Standard_A6",
    "Standard_A7",
    "Standard_A8",
    "Standard_A9",
    "Standard_A10",
    "Standard_A11",
    "Standard_D1",
    "Standard_D2",
    "Standard_D3",
    "Standard_D3_v2",
    "Standard_D4",
    "Standard_D4_v2",
    "Standard_D5_v2",
    "Standard_D11",
    "Standard_D12",
    "Standard_D12_v2",
    "Standard_D13",
    "Standard_D13_v2",
    "Standard_D14",
    "Standard_D14_v2",
    "Standard_DS3",
    "Standard_DS4",
    "Standard_DS12",
    "Standard_DS13",
    "Standard_DS14",
    "Standard_G2",
    "Standard_G3",
    "Standard_G4",
    "Standard_G5",
    "Standard_GS2",
    "Standard_GS3",
    "Standard_GS4",
    "Standard_GS5",
    "Standard_D2s_v3"
   ],
   "metadata": {
    "description": "Size of the VMs to be used for actual computation."
   }
  },
  "computeOSType": {
   "type": "string",
   "defaultValue": "Linux",
   "allowedValues": [
    "Linux",
    "Windows"
   ],
   "metadata": {
    "description": "Compute OS Type"
   }
  },
  "deploymentType": {
   "type": "string",
   "defaultValue": "VMSS",
   "allowedValues": [
    "VMSS",
    "Single",
    "SingleAV"
   ],
   "metadata": {
    "description": "This determines whether the VMs will be deployed using scale sets, as individual VMs, or individual VMs in an availability set (maximum 100 for the last option)."
   }
  },
  "numberOfSAs": {
   "type": "int",
   "metadata": {
    "description": "Number of Storage Accounts to upload the custom image to."
   }
  },
  "instanceCountPerSA": {
   "type": "int",
   "maxValue": 40,
   "metadata": {
    "description": "Number of VMs per Storage Account."
   }
  },
  "imageLocation": {
   "type": "string",
   "metadata": {
    "description": "URL of the base custom image, in the format of https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/container/image.vhd."
   }
  },
  "storageAccountKey": {
   "type": "securestring",
   "metadata": {
    "description": "Storage Account key for accessing the base custom image."
   }
  },
  "adminUsername": {
   "type": "string",
   "metadata": {
    "description": "Admin username for the VMs in the deployment."
   }
  },
  "adminPassword": {
   "type": "securestring",
   "metadata": {
    "description": "Admin password for the VMs in the deployment."
   }
  }
 },
 "variables": {
  "vnetName": "[concat(parameters('uniquePrefix'), 'vnet')]",
  "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/16",
  "subnetName": "subnet",
  "subnetPrefix": "10.0.0.0/21",
  "transferImagePublisher": "Canonical",
  "transferImageOffer": "UbuntuServer",
  "ubuntuOSVersion": "16.04-LTS",
  "imagePieces": "[split(parameters('imageLocation'),'/')]",
  "blobName": "blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net",
  "templateLocation": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/301-custom-images-at-scale/",
  "sharedResourcesTemplateUri ": "[concat(variables('templateLocation'), 'shared-resources.json')]",
  "finalTemplateUri": "[concat(variables('templateLocation'), 'final_')]",
  "downloadTemplateURI": "[concat(variables('templateLocation'), 'download.json')]",
  "downloadScriptURI": "[concat(variables('templateLocation'), 'download.sh')]",
  "uploadTemplateURI": "[concat(variables('templateLocation'), 'upload.json')]",
        "uploadScriptURI": "[concat(variables('templateLocation'), 'upload.sh')]",
        "vmStorageAccountContainerName": "transfertestsa",
        "OSDiskName": "transfertestvm",
        "StorageAccountName": "transfertest"
 },
 "resources": [{
   "name": "[concat(parameters('uniquePrefix'), 'base')]",
   "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
   "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
   "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "templateLink": {
     "uri": "[variables('sharedResourcesTemplateUri ')]",
     "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
    },
    "parameters": {
     "uniquePrefix": {
      "value": "[parameters('uniquePrefix')]"
     },
     "numberOfSAs": {
      "value": "[parameters('numberOfSAs')]"
     },
     "vnetName": {
      "value": "[variables('vnetName')]"
     },
     "addressPrefix": {
      "value": "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
     },
     "subnetName": {
      "value": "[variables('subnetName')]"
     },
     "subnetPrefix": {
      "value": "[variables('subnetPrefix')]"
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
   "name": "[concat('transfer', parameters('uniquePrefix'), 'sa')]",
   "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
   "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
   "properties": {
    "accountType": "Standard_LRS"
   }
  },
  {
   "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
   "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
   "name": "[concat('transfer', parameters('uniquePrefix'), 'ip')]",
   "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
   "properties": {
    "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"
   }
  },
  {
   "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
   "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
   "name": "[concat('transfer', parameters('uniquePrefix'), 'nic')]",
   "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
   "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/transfer', parameters('uniquePrefix'), 'ip')]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Resources/deployments/', parameters('uniquePrefix'), 'base')]"
   ],
   "properties": {
    "ipConfigurations": [{
     "name": "ipconfig1",
     "properties": {
      "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
      "publicIPAddress": {
       "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', concat('transfer', parameters('uniquePrefix'), 'ip'))]"
      },
      "subnet": {
       "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('vnetName'), '/subnets/', variables('subnetName'))]"
      }
     }
    }]
   }
  },
  {
   "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
   "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
   "name": "[concat('transfer', parameters('uniquePrefix'), 'vm')]",
   "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
   "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/transfer', parameters('uniquePrefix'), 'sa')]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/transfer', parameters('uniquePrefix'), 'nic')]"
   ],
   "properties": {
    "hardwareProfile": {
     "vmSize": "[parameters('transferVMSize')]"
    },
    "osProfile": {
     "computerName": "[concat('transfer', parameters('uniquePrefix'), 'vm')]",
     "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
     "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
    },
    "storageProfile": {
     "imageReference": {
      "publisher": "[variables('transferImagePublisher')]",
      "offer": "[variables('transferImageOffer')]",
      "sku": "[variables('ubuntuOSVersion')]",
      "version": "latest"
     },
    "osDisk": {
     "name": "osdisk",
     "vhd": {
      "uri": "[concat(reference(concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/',variables('vmStorageAccountContainerName'),''), '2015-06-15').primaryEndpoints.blob,'vhds/',variables('OSDiskName'),'-osdisk.vhd')]"
      },
      "caching": "ReadWrite",
      "createOption": "FromImage"
     }
    },
    "networkProfile": {
     "networkInterfaces": [{
      "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', concat('transfer', parameters('uniquePrefix'), 'nic'))]"
     }]
    },
    "diagnosticsProfile": {
     "bootDiagnostics": {
      "enabled": "true",
      "storageUri": "[concat('http://transfer',parameters('uniquePrefix'),'sa.blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net')]"
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "name": "[concat(parameters('uniquePrefix'), 'script0')]",
   "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
   "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
   "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/transfer', parameters('uniquePrefix'), 'vm')]"
   ],
   "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "templateLink": {
     "uri": "[variables('downloadTemplateURI')]",
     "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
    },
    "parameters": {
     "uniquePrefix": {
      "value": "[parameters('uniquePrefix')]"
     },
     "imageLocation": {
      "value": "[parameters('imageLocation')]"
     },
     "storageAccountKey": {
      "value": "[parameters('storageAccountKey')]"
     },
     "downloadScriptURI": {
      "value": "[variables('downloadScriptURI')]"
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "name": "[concat(parameters('uniquePrefix'), 'script', string(add(copyIndex(), 1)))]",
   "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
   "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
   "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Resources/deployments/', parameters('uniquePrefix'), 'script', copyIndex())]"
   ],
   "copy": {
    "name": "uploadLoop",
    "count": "[parameters('numberOfSAs')]"
   },
   "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "templateLink": {
     "uri": "[variables('uploadTemplateURI')]",
     "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
    },
    "parameters": {
     "uniquePrefix": {
      "value": "[parameters('uniquePrefix')]"
     },
     "index": {
      "value": "[copyIndex()]"
     },
     "uploadScriptURI": {
      "value": "[variables('uploadScriptURI')]"
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "name": "[concat(parameters('uniquePrefix'), 'full')]",
   "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
   "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
   "dependsOn": [
    "uploadLoop"
   ],
   "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "templateLink": {
     "uri": "[concat(variables('finalTemplateUri'), parameters('deploymentType'), '.json')]",
     "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
    },
    "parameters": {
     "uniquePrefix": {
      "value": "[parameters('uniquePrefix')]"
     },
     "numberOfSAs": {
      "value": "[parameters('numberOfSAs')]"
     },
     "instanceCountPerSA": {
      "value": "[parameters('instanceCountPerSA')]"
     },
     "vmSize": {
      "value": "[parameters('computeVMSize')]"
     },
     "OSType": {
      "value": "[parameters('computeOSType')]"
     },
     "blobName": {
      "value": "[variables('blobName')]"
     },
     "vnetName": {
      "value": "[variables('vnetName')]"
     },
     "addressPrefix": {
      "value": "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
     },
     "subnetName": {
      "value": "[variables('subnetName')]"
     },
     "subnetPrefix": {
      "value": "[variables('subnetPrefix')]"
     },
     "templateLocation": {
      "value": "[variables('templateLocation')]"
     },
     "adminUsername": {
      "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
     },
     "adminPassword": {
      "value": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
     }
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

The above is what I am using to launch my template and attached are the parameters that I am inputting and the error message I receive. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOoJN.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5N6T.png)

Comment: Please post your errors as text not images, its much easier to inspect or search / you'll get a better response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error by forking the script to my own repo and changing every occurrence of the blob reference to gov cloud in all the files needed for that script.